# jquery autocomplete - Menu doesn't open when key up/down for navigation

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I like to navigate with keys from input to input. If the input field is a jquery autocomplete element, the menu open on key down/up. How can i stop to open the menu, when I'm navigating and not changing anything?

Comment: can you provide some code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you only general hints, because of code snippet absence. You have two options to achieve this:

1. disable autocomplete and enable it when element was changed
2. use delay to show autocomplete dropdown after some time interval

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I searched 4 hours and i was so close. Thank you for the right hint! Disable and enable on change is the solution.